# Applying Wood Conditioner to Pine - How much should I use?

Tags: woodworking, stain, varnishing

I have a pine window sill that was beat up over 40 years. I sanded it (down to 60 grit with sandpaper frequently clogging), applied wood preconditioner, and tonight I applied the stain (oil based). What I found when I applied the stain was that the pine just drank it up like crazy. I used a rag to smooth it out over the wood and a little spoon to pour.

When you use preconditioner, do you fellows ever apply more than one coat? How would you know when to stop? I attached a picture of the wood and you can see it patches all over the place. There was a strange board too that looked "dirty" after I sanded it in that it was gray. You can't see that in the photo.

[image]

Comment: what are the manufacturer's instructions?

Comment: Put a coat on, lightly sand. Not much else.